# How do I export GLBudgetLineDetail via Rest API?

Tags: rest, acumatica

My goal is to export data from the [GLBudgetlineDetail] table via the Rest API.

To accomplish this:
1) I created created a custom endpoint based on the Budgets screen (Finance > General Ledger > Work Area > Enter > Budgets)
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXdSk.jpg)

2) I populated the endpoint by adding all the fields from the Budget Articles container
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FvD5.jpg)

When I query this endpoint, I only get an empty array returned "[]".

Here is the query:

GET http ://servername/WebServiceAPITest/entity/MyStore/6.00.001/Budget

Headers: 
Content-Type -> application/json
("Budget" is the name I gave to the endpoint)

I can successfully query other endpoints (Accounts, Vendors, JournalTransactions, etc) but I can't get any data back from this one.

I created the MyStore Demo (Course I210) and have access to the [GLBudgetLineDetail] table and can verify that it has data. On the Budgets screen, if I filter to year 2013, Ledger 'Budget', Branch 'SOFT', I can see Budget information.

How do I get access to this info via the Rest API?

Comment: Can you post the query that you are using

Comment: Sure thing:
GET http://servername/WebServiceAPITest/entity/MyStore/6.00.001/Budget 
Headers: Content-Type -> application/json

Comment: @Ryan, could you please also provide a couple screenshots of your custom endpoint, specifically showing the mapping done for the *Budget* entity?

Comment: I have added links to screenshots of the custom endpoint in the post. Let me know if they weren't what you were looking for.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned the Course I210, You might want to refer yourself to the section 3.4.1 about Retrieving the Price of an Item for a Customer.
In that section, they are saying that if you want to retrieve data from an inquiry, you must use the Put command:
"Because you are retrieving the price of an item from the inquiry, you will use the Put() method to obtain data."
Since the Budget Screen is an Inquiry Screen you must use the Put command to set the parameter you want.

Here is one that I tried and that worked on an Acumatica web site with demo 
data:

PUT http://localhost/Demo610u04/entity/BudgetEndpoint/6.00.001/Budget

Headers (Key -> Value):

```
Content-Type -> application/json  
Accept -> application/json
```

Body :

```
{
    "BudgetArticles":[{}],
    "FinancialYear":{"Value":"2016"},
    "Ledger":{"Value":"BUDGET"}
}
```

EDIT: Looking at the image you added, you should have your budget Filter fields in the main entity and have a sub entity of type Detail containing the Budget Articles fields

Comment: thanks for your feedback; I have not yet had success and have tried the following steps:

- Created a new instance with the SalesDemo data

- Extended the Default 6.00.001 endpoint

- Added a Top-Level entity based on Budgets; populated it from the Budget Filters container
!(http://imgur.com/VdDQwPK)

- Added a Detail entity named BudgetArticles; populated it from the Budget Articles container

- Logged in using Company + Branch in the credentials

- Submitted a PUT request: response has a header entity, but no BudgetArticles
!(http://imgur.com/H2SIjqa)

Comment: Also, I noticed that you wrote that the Budget Screen is an Inquiry Screen. Is there a way that I can tell when a given screen is an Inquiry Screen and therefore GET requests won't work? (ex: JournalTransactions can be accessed with GET)